# Which gnome is the tallest?

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

This is a riddle I and some friends came up with. Say I have four gnomes with different heights. They state the following:

Gnome 1: I am the shortest.

Gnome 2: I am neither the tallest nor the shortest.

Gnome 3: I am the tallest.

Gnome 4: I am not the shortest.

Exactly one of the gnomes is lying. Which gnome is the tallest?

Comment: I enjoy seeing these simpler puzzles on Puzzling because I know that I'll actually be able to do them, and not just have to read the question & answer and wonder how in the world Stiv&Co figured out the solution.

Comment: ^and I mean no shade to the power users, they're brilliant and I enjoy reading their puzzles and answers, but I like being able to figure out the puzzles myself sometimes.

Comment: @RobinClower don't be afraid to post your own answer if it hasn't been covered by existing answers :D

Comment: At the circus: “Here you can see the world's largest dwarf and the world's smallest giant! They look exactly alike – two ordinary people.”

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Gnome 1 cannot be lying because if 2, 3 and 4 are all telling the truth, none of them is the shortest gnome.
>
>  So gnome 1 is telling the truth, which means that gnome 4 automatically tells the truth. So the liar must be 2 or 3.
>
>  If gnome 2 is lying, he must be the tallest gnome (since gnome 1 tells the truth and is therefore the shortest). But that would mean gnome 3 is lying as well, and both can't be lying. So gnome 2 tells the truth.
>
>  All this means gnome 3 is lying (so he is not the tallest gnome). Also gnome 1 and 2 are truthfully claiming not to be the tallest gnome, making **gnome 4** the tallest gnome.

Comment: Very nicely done.  I would just elaborate that final statement to perhaps complete the explanation: Gnome 4 telling the truth does not alone make Gnome 4 clearly the tallest.  However,  given that Gnome 3 is the one lying, we see from their own statements that Gnome 1 is the shortest and Gnome 2 and 3 are NOT the tallest, leaving only Gnome 4 to be the tallest.

Comment: A clearer way of saying "4 vf gryyvat gur gehgu"(rot13) is maybe "Vs 4 vf ylvat gura 1 naq 4 ner obgu fubegrfg"(rot13)?

Comment: Hello. Newbie here. What does your comment mean @SamDean?

Comment: @Ramy it's a cypher. Presumably since you can't use spoiler tags in comments. Checkout https://cryptii.com/pipes/rot13-decoder

Comment: @Ramy As THE JOATMON said it's a cypher that just changes letters to the ones 13 letters later. I use the following Chrome extension to easily do it. Just highlight some text, right click, select the Rot13 option https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rot13/bahejodllcomogcpgnidcdaiidfmhomh

Answer (score 8):

Same answer, different logic.

> If #1 is the tallest then he is lying. But then #3 is truthful and contradicts #1 being tallest.
>
>  If #2 is the tallest then he is lying. But then #3 is truthful and contradicts #2 being tallest.
>
>  If #3 is the tallest then he tells the truth.  But then, either #1 is truthful, he is shortest and everybody tells the truth or #1 lies and nobody is shortest. In both cases a contradiction.
>
>  So, #4 is the tallest.
>
>  And it follows that #3 lies and #1 is truthful and shortest.  We don't know which of #2 and #3 is taller.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach, based on figuring out which gnome is lying.

> Suppose Gnome 1 is lying. Then none of the gnomes are the shortest, which is impossible.
>
>  Suppose Gnome 2 is lying. Then all of Gnomes 1, 2, and 3 are either the tallest or the shortest, which is impossible.
>
>  Suppose Gnome 4 is lying. Then both Gnomes 2 and 4 are the shortest, which is impossible.
>
>  So Gnome 3 is the liar. We therefore know that Gnomes 1, 2, and 3 are not the tallest, so Gnome 4 is the tallest.
>
>  We also know that Gnome 1 is the shortest, while Gnomes 2 and 3 are in between, in some order.

Comment: I went with the same logic